# Will there be more than 11 million job openings related to Data Science in India by 2026?

Tags: economics, education, india, mathematics, forecasting

This [Career Outlook for Data Scientist](https://www.indiatoday.in/education-today/jobs-and-careers/story/career-outlook-for-data-scientists-in-india-sky-high-pay-and-rising-demand-1825991-2021-07-09) article claims that analyst predict that there will be more than 11 million job openings by 2026 in the field of data science.

Does this claim makes sense given the market conditions? Also article claims about 93k job positions being vacant at end of August 2020 true?

Comment: As the question is asking for a crystal ball into 2026, perhaps it should be asked on [SE Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) itself.